# Lookup Site Column, broken item link when added to list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

On my parent site, I added a list, populated it and then created a site column that is a lookup to a column in said list.

I then added a sub site, created a new list and added the site column to it. Now, when I create an item in the sub site list, the lookup works fine as expected, but when I click on the item, I get a pop up message saying something went wrong and the only thing I get when I click on technical details is a guid...

[image: This is the error message I get when I click on the item in my list]
What I think is happening is sharepoint looks for the list on the subsite, but it's not there, it's on the parent site.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to SPManger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try and get SPManager installed. Once you have done this you will be able to drill down in to the field and it's underlying settings(e.g what list and where it's looking for it).

You can also inspect the underlying properties of the field with powershell. Until you have done this and identified what is actually happening we can't help much more without investing more time in trying to replicate your issue.

Cheers

Truez